# Container view getting truncated despite constraints in place

Tags: swift, uicontainerview

[image: Here's a picture.]

The scene has a container view inside of a superview, and I've constrained it with respect to the boundaries and 2 text boxes. Instead of "Numeric Value Please", I only see `Nu...` appearing on there. The console does not give me any constraint related warnings, and I don't understand why the blue view is able to fit in, but the controller is not.

Here are `Alert Controller`'s constraints: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xhZh.png. It's just constrained to the center.

Another picture of main view's constraints: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qARq.png

Comment: @Snusmumrikken Here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XoiYi.png. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Content hugging and resizing is identical for both the container view and left textfield: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OTmMQ.png

Comment: ```What do you want when the superview widths changes? ``` - I haven't thought about that actually..I suppose I'd like both to resize proportionally as the superview's size changes. Why would it though?

Comment: Just get rid of the `Trailing Space` constraint in the `ContainerView` and instead, set the `Width`. But why are you using a `ContainerView` anyway?

Comment: @alaphao I don't know, I was just experimenting. I could just work with a simple dialog box here. I need the thing to show up only when the user enters a non-numeric value, which is doable with UIView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraint to the right is too large (125), pushing the right edge of the container to the left.

You should just have: constraint from top (superview), constraint to left (the text field), height (optional), and slightly higher compression resistance. To prevent the text from going off to the right you can also have a `>=` constraint to the right (superview).

To break the text into two lines, set number of lines to `2` and choose "Word Wrap" + make sure you have a right side constraint and you are not constraining the height (too much).

Another remark: do you really need a "container" view? Why not just a plain UIView? Or does the label have its own controller? That seems like a somewhat convoluted design I think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to meddle around with what you said. now. I believe you're right, I could just work with a simple dialog box here. I need the thing to show up only when the user enters a non-numeric value, which is doable with UIView.